# SignalR Web API send message to current user

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I have web app project and an angular 2 project. 
I would like use SignalR to send message from the server.
Then I found this [article](https://blog.sstorie.com/integrating-angular2-and-signalr-part-1/) about implementing it.
But I don't know how to send message to the current user.

Code for send message C#:

```
public class EventHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task Subscribe(string channel)
        {
            await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, channel);

            var @event = new ChannelEvent
            {
                Name = $"{Context.ConnectionId} subscribed",
                Data = new
                {
                    Context.ConnectionId,
                    ChannelName = channel
                }
            };

            await Publish(@event);
        }

        public async Task Unsubscribe(string channel)
        {
            await Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, channel);

            var @event = new ChannelEvent
            {
                Name = $"{Context.ConnectionId} unsubscribed",
                Data = new
                {
                    Context.ConnectionId,
                    ChannelName = channel
                }
            };

            await Publish(@event);
        }

        public Task Publish(ChannelEvent channelEvent)
        {
            Clients.Caller.OnEvent(Constants.AdminChannel, channelEvent);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            var @event = new ChannelEvent
            {
                Name = $"{Context.ConnectionId} connected",
                Data = new
                {
                    Context.ConnectionId,
                }
            };

            Publish(@event);

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            var @event = new ChannelEvent
            {
                Name = $"{Context.ConnectionId} disconnected",
                Data = new
                {
                    Context.ConnectionId,
                }
            };

            Publish(@event);

            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
    }

public static class Constants
    {
        public const string AdminChannel = "admin";
        public const string TaskChannel = "tasks";
    }

public class ChannelEvent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ChannelName { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }

        public object Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set
            {
                _data = value;
                Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);
            }
        }
        private object _data;

        public string Json { get; private set; }

        public ChannelEvent()
        {
            Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        }
    }
```

Then in my controller I create **IhubContent**

```
private readonly IHubContext _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<EventHub>();
```

and invoke my publish event:

```
private void PublishEvent(string eventName, StatusModel status)
{
    _context.Clients.Group(Constants.TaskChannel).OnEvent(Constants.TaskChannel, new ChannelEvent
    {
        ChannelName = Constants.TaskChannel,
        Name = eventName,
        Data = status
    });
}
```

But this message sent to all users. Help me to fix this issue and implement code to the send message to the current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IHubContext object your are using has multiple methods, one of which is `Clients`, of type [IHubConnectionContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.ihubconnectioncontext(v=vs.118).aspx).

In there you have `Groups`, `Group`, `Clients` & `Client` methods which abstract what you want to target.

In your case using:

```
_context.Clients.Client(connectionId).send(message);
```

should be working fine (you still need to propagate the connectionId though).

N.B.: `send` is a JS method that should be implemented on client-side.

Comment: userId you mean Context.ConnectionId? Or some else?

Comment: Bad typo, you have to use `Client` method to address a user with its connectionId; `User` can be used in case of addressing users with their [username](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)